# What is the difference between genericModel and defaultModel in wicket?

Tags: wicket

I am new to wicket. There is a confusion in Model, `ModelObject` defaultModel, `genericModel`. I need to know the difference between `ModelObject` and `Model`, `defaultModel` and `genericModel`. Please help me to clear about it.

Comment: Please read out the document:https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/6.x/guide/modelsforms.html

Comment: Model is kind of ... "container", or "proxy", or "envelope" to get when reguired ModelObject .... Word Model has generally common meaning in OOP, not only Wicket. ModelObject is simple data You want: person name, invoice amount etc

Answer (score 2):

`defaultModel[Object]` and `genericModel[Object]` is the same object, behind the scenes.

Each `Component` has an `IModel` and this model brings an `java.lang.Object` inside. This is the `defaultModelObject`.

Some specializations of `Component`, like `FormComponent`, `Form`, `GenericPanel`, etc. use Java generics to make the user code more concrete. For this Wicket uses `genericModel[Object]` - it is the same Object but casted to its actual type. The casting is in Wicket code, not in the application code.